# "end-point DllRegisterServer was not found" Error

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, dll

I'm trying to install Assassin's creed 3 (blackbox). While installing, an error popped up saying isdone.dll was not found.
Proceeding to rectify it, I downloaded isdone.dll (from dll-files website).
Then extracted the file and copied it to
**C:\windows\system32**
and **C:\windows\syswow64**.

Now, to register the dll, I used regsvr32 (in system32 folder) command in cmd(elevated mode). It flashed the error: "*The module isdone.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found*".

I tried the following, but none of them helped!

1. Tried regsvr32 command in syswow64 folder! ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIkqK.png))
2. Cleared registries using ccleaner.
3. Tried DLL-files fixer software.
4. Tried installing in clean boot.
5. Tried DllInstall method. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4hpd.png))

None of these worked.

Is there any other way to register dll files? Or maybe  this isdone.dll is not valid? (I think this is the issue)
If this is so, where can I find 'isdone.dll' for windows 8.1 64 bit?
Anyone who could help me with this please?

using Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: Anyone who could help me with this?

Comment: [See if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit)